# Exchanging variables between two pages PHP

Tags: php, session, post, get

I am aware that this kind of question has already been asked before, but I have a slightly different case.

```
foreach($dir as $file) 
{ 
    $file = '<li><a href="test.php?file='.basename($file).'">'.basename($file).'</a></li>';
    echo $file; 
}
```

This is my script to display files in a folder and link to them. The way it is now, I use the `$_GET['file']` on the other page to receive the information on the other page. The other page is supposed to display a photo/video with the file that has been linked, however I don't know how to use the `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` in this case, since it's a loop and I don't want the information about the file be in the link.

Also, I don't want any forms. I want to click the link with the name of the file and the other website to already have the information about the file and display the video or image.

Comment: To clarify: why do you need `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` here? What information about the file can't you get across in the link?

Comment: basically `$_SESSSION['file']=basename($file);`

Comment: Hello, I dont want the name of the file to be in the link, since if someone knew the direct link, he would be able to access the file. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this by storing the media path in session and use the corresponding index to pass.

First file:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
session_start();
$dir = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
echo '<ul>';
foreach($dir as $file) 
{ //echo $i.'---'.$file."<br />";
    echo '<li><a href="test.php?file='. $i .'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    $_SESSION['media_'.$i] = $file;
    $i++;
} 
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['media_'.$_GET['file']];
?>
```

Comment: Hello, for some reason this piece of code maps every link onto one file and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are sure that $dir contains distinct filenames?

Comment: Yes, each of the files is named differently.

Comment: Can you try printing the session there itself. Check what is the result?

Comment: Yes, I did that. The session prints the name of the file that all the links are mapped to.

Comment: Works splendid. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you rep, since I'm new here. ;/

Comment: I realize that the important concept here is to pass an ID number and use it to reference an array of file paths. However, this method could be simplified by combining all code in one file. Then you won't need to use sessions.

Comment: @showdev Then how you will access that in the action page without using session?

Comment: I'm suggesting that, if all the code exists in one file (i.e. the page links to itself), you can translate the index fetched from $_GET data to a file path stored in an array. e.g. `echo $dir[$_GET['file']];` Food for thought.

Comment: Oh.. Okay, If you are keeping a naming convention like this, its cool.